# get the values of elements in the list which occurs only twice not more than twice

Tags: python, list, element

I have a list of elements I want to store that elements in the list which occur only twice not more than twice or less than twice.Below is the list

```
list = [595, 595, 344, 344, 628, 628, 628, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353]
```

From the list I want the output to be `result = [595,344]`

The below code returns only one element

```
def has1dup(lst):
    setlst = list(set(lst)) # no duplicate elements
    for i in range(len(setlst)): # while the setlist's element count, 
        if lst.count(setlst[i]) > 1: # if the count of setlist[i] of lst is bigger than 1
            return setlst[i] # return it
```

Comment: Do you need to keep the original order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here use this:

```
lst2 = list(set([x for x in lst if lst.count(x)==2]))
```

use this if you don't want to change the order:

```
lst = [595, 595, 344, 344, 628, 628, 628, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353]
lst2=[]
[lst2.append(x) for x in lst if lst.count(x)==2 and x not in lst2]
print(lst2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `Counter` from `collections`.

e.g.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [595, 595, 344, 344, 628, 628, 628, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353]
>>> new_dict=Counter(l)
>>> new_dict
Counter({353: 5, 628: 3, 595: 2, 344: 2})
>>> [key for key, val in new_dict.items() if val == 2]
[595, 344]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the second element because you are using the `return` statement.

Instead use something like the following

```
mylist = [595, 595, 344, 344, 628, 628, 628, 353, 353, 353, 353, 353]
newlist = []
def has1dup(lst):
    setlst = list(set(lst)) # no duplicate elements
    for i in range(len(setlst)): # while the setlist's element count,
        if lst.count(setlst[i]) == 2: # if the count of setlist[i] of lst is bigger than 1
            newlist.append(setlst[i])

has1dup(mylist)
print(newlist)
```

Output

```
[344, 595]
```

Now in the above case we have declared a new list called `newlist`. For every element in the set for which its count in the list is exactly `2`, we append it to a new list.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a results list, and append setlst[i] to the results list as opposed to returning it right away. Then, return the results list.